# ¿Cómo Obtener promedio de una columna calculada?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Como puedo sacar el promedio de una consulta Mysql para poder usarla en Laravel

```
SELECT start as fecha, 
       COUNT(IF(active = 0,1,NULL)) as totalir, 
       COUNT(start) as totalit, 
       round(COUNT(IF(active = 0,1,NULL)) / COUNT(start) * 100, 2) as porcentaje 
FROM incidences 
WHERE MONTH(start) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) 
AND YEAR(start) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
GROUP BY start
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que debería ser algo así, aun me estoy iniciando en laravel y no sé como hacer la consulta:

```
$tri = DB::select('SELECT start as fecha, 
                          COUNT(IF(active = 0,1,NULL)) as totalir, 
                          COUNT(start) as totalit, round(COUNT(IF(active = 0,1,NULL)) / COUNT(start) * 100, 2) as porcentaje 
                   FROM incidences 
                   WHERE MONTH(start) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) 
                   AND YEAR(start) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) 
                   GROUP BY start');
```

Esta es la vista, por ahora solo estoy mostrando el porcentaje. Lo que me gustaría es poder **mostrar el promedio de la columna porcentaje**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Si tengo creado el modelo y todo funciona bien. Lo que busco es poder sacar el promedio de la columna porcentaje

Comment: como dijo @BetaM desaprovechas el queryb te recomiendo usarlo `$tri = DB::table->('incidences')
            ->select('start as date',
                                'COUNT(IF(active = 0,1,NULL)) as totalir', 'COUNT(start) as totalit',
                                'round(AVG(COUNT(IF(active = 0,1,NULL)) / COUNT(start) * 100), 2) as porcentaje')
            ->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->where('MONTH(start)', '=', 'MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())')
                          ->where('YEAR(start)', '=', 'YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())');
            })->groupBy('start')->get();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Parte 1**

Te comparto esta consulta:

```
$mesActual = now()->month;
$anioActual = now()->year;

$tri = Incidencie::select('start as fecha')
            ->selectRaw('COUNT(IF(inactive = 0, 1, NULL)) AS totaldir')
            ->selectRaw('COUNT(start) AS totalit')
            ->selectRaw('round(COUNT(IF(active = 0,1,NULL)) / COUNT(start) * 100, 2) AS porcentaje')
            ->whereMonth('start', $mesActual)
            ->whereYear('start', $anioActual)
            ->groupBy('fecha')
            ->get();
```

Explico:

- Hago uso del modelo Incidencie (*si no existe se crea*)
- Para obtener el número de mes así como el año podemos auxiliarnos de *Carbon* y de las propiedades `month` y `year`
- Para pasar consultas SQL en su estado puro, usamos el método `selectRaw`, (*podríamos pasar todas las funciones de agregación dentro de una misma, pero por legibilidad preferí declarar estas en mas de un método*)
- Para filtrar con base en el mes, usamos el método `whereMonth` así como `whereYear` para el caso del año
- Por cierto en tu agrupamiento idealmente para ocupar lo declarado, hazlo por el alias que le diste a `start` es decir `fecha`

De esta forma tendrás una consulta mejor estructurada y aprovechando mucho del *query builder* que a través de sus métodos hace mas legible tu sentencia SQL

**Parte 2**

Ahora para no cargarle a la vista una tarea extra, podemos considerar:

- En el controlador declarar una variable que inicialmente valdrá 0 (*misma que usaremos primero para sumar todos los valores de la columna porcentaje*)

  ```
  $sumatoriaPorcentajes = 0;
  ```
- Posterior puedes iterar con un *foreach* la colección pero en el controlador para ir acumulando la suma de todos los valores que la columna porcentajes posee quedando así:

  ```
  foreach ($tri as $promedio) {
      $sumatoriaPorcentajes += $promedio->porcentaje;
  }
  ```
- Finalmente para obtener el promedio de esta sumatoria dividimos el total que tiene sumado `$sumatoriaPorcentajes` y lo dividimos entre el número que nos arroje el conteo de objetos que nos retorna la colección así:

  ```
  $promedioPorcentajes = $sumatoriaPorcentajes / count($tri);
  ```

De este modo podrás mandar a la vista 2 variables:

- `$tri` que es tu colección original y te permitirá poblar tu tabla con los datos
- `$promedioPorcentajes` que contiene el promedio de la columna deseada

Ya solo te resta armar tu tabla y acomodar la impresión del promedio donde necesites

**Referencias**

- [Revisa el apartado sentencias where adicionales](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses)
- [Método selectRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods)

Comment: Gracias! @BetaM esta es la solución que realmente buscaba.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [`collections`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections), dado que ya hiciste la consulta, entonces simplemente requieres de un cálculo, en este caso `avg` que es el promedio.

En tu vista blade, puedes convertir tu array en una colección y usar el método [`avg()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-avg) que provee laravel collection.

Entonces, en tu vista, quedaría algo así:

```
@foreach($tri as $item)
     {{ $item->porcentaje }}
@endforeach

@php
     $promedio = collect($tri)->avg('porcentaje');
@endphp
<label>Promedio del porcentaje {{ $promedio }}</label>
```

Primero, como dije antes, debes convertir tu array en una instancia de collection, una vez hecho eso, usas el método `avg()` que, dado que tu array tiene llave y valor, puedes pasarle la llave por la que quieres que se haga el promedio, en este caso `porcentaje`.

Comment: Gracias @L.Flor me ayudo mucho el usar collect para lo que necesitaba